# Why is the pointer not de-referenced in the function max?

Tags: c

```
// function t find the max value entered in the array
    double max(double *n,int size)
    {
        int i,k=0;
        double *maxi;
        maxi=&k;

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(*maxi<n[i])
            {
                maxi=&n[i];
            }
        }
        return *maxi;
    }
//elements of array are added
    main()
    {
        double a[10000],maxi;
        int size,i;
        printf("enter the size of the array");
        scanf("%d",&size);
        printf("enter the elements of array");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            scanf("%lf",&a[i]);
        }
        maxi=max(&a,size);
        printf("maximum value is %lf",maxi);
    }
```

Why is the pointer not de-referenced in the function max? If I de-reference the pointer `n` it gives an error. If there is a better way to do this, please suggest.

Comment: _It gives an error_ is not a very helpful description, please elaborate your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: There's a minor discrepancy in your call `max(&a,size)` which is probably giving you a compiler warning. It should be either `max(a,size)` or `max(&a[0],size)`. Both of those pass a pointer to the first element of the array (which is the correct pointer type `double *`), rather than pass a pointer to the whole array (which is the wrong pointer type `double (*)[10000]`).

Answer (score 0):

`n[i]` is the very same thing as `*(n + i)`. So the pointer is de-referenced, through the [] syntax.

As for why you are getting an error, it is impossible to tell without you posting the problematic code.

Comment: But note that `&n[i];` doesn't actually *deference* the pointer. C *must* evaluate this as `n + i`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the array/pointer as argument and dereferencing are both wrong.

```
maxi=max(&a,size); // passing address of the address

if(*maxi<n[i]) // k is compared to memory garbage

maxi=&n[i]; // maxi is assigned with memory garbage
```

Consider following:

```
double max( double * na, int size ) // n changed to na
{
    int idx; // changed i to idx; 
    double max; // forget about k and maxi, just simply max
    if( 0 < size )
    {
        max = na[0]; // init max to 1st elem
        for( idx = 1; idx < size; ++idx ) // iterate from 2nd elem
        {
            if( max < na[idx] ) { max = na[idx]; } // check for larger
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    double an[10000],maxi; // a changed to an
    // ..
    maxi = max( an, size ); // pass an not &an
    // ..
    return 0;
}
```